# In Python: Replacing multiple characters in a string

Tags: python

Given random string: x= "afffbeeec"
I want to apply the following changes:

1. Replace x[0] with x[len(x)//2] # bfffbeeec
2. Replace x[len(x)//2] with original x[-1] # bfffceeec
3. Replace x[-1] with original x[0] # bfffceeea

Is there a more elegnt way than doing it like this:

```
x = "afffbeeec"
new_x = x[len (x)//2] + x[1:len(x)//2] + \
        x[-1] + x[len(x)//2 + 1:-1] + x[0]
print(new_x)
```

I've tried ".replace", "list" + "join" and "index" methods.

Comment: More elegant in what way?

Comment: If you have contrived requirements then your code is going to look contrived.

Comment: Why not encapsulate this logic into its own function if elegance is what you require?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python strings are immutable so you can't assign characters at specific indexes. But you can turn the string into a list, perform the swapping and turn the list back into a string afterward:

```
 iMid = len(x)//2
 L    = list(x)
 L[0],L[iMid],L[-1] = x[iMid],x[-1],x[0]
 x    = "".join(L)

 # bfffceeea
```

A more generalized approach would be to use a dictionary of position mappings and use it to rebuild the string:

```
posMap = {0:len(x)//2, len(x)//2:-1, -1:0}
x = "".join(x[posMap.get(i,i)] for i in range(len(x)))
```

You could also map directly to the assignment characters rather than positions:

```
iMid = len(x)//2
charMap = {0:x[iMid], iMid:x[-1], -1:x[0]}
x = "".join(charMap.get(i,c) for i,c in enumerate(x))
```